# Export Infopath Form from SharePoint List

Tags: 2010, list, document-library, infopath

I have a List that uses an Infopath form. Is it possible to extract the actual Infopath xml document. The idea is I want to have a process where I extract the item as xml as dump it in a document library for archive. I am looking for either OOB or code solutions.

Moving the form to a document library is not an option as some of the required fields cannot be promoted (e.g. people picker fields). I need these for some workflows I have on that list.

The solution needs to be automated, via a workflow which will be triggered by the Information Policy settings.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are able to do this when using a Form Library, because it saves the actual infopath form in the library. When using a list with an InfoPath form, it doesn't save the form as such, but it pushes the values into the list as a list item. You might be able to open up the list item in the form and then save/export that form from InfoPath filler / designer ?

If having a document library of InfoPath forms is what you want, you could design a new form where you are able to select a list item from the original list, use the InfoPath actions / rules to copy the values over into controls inside the form and than save that form in your "archive" form library.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately moving the form to a document library is not an option as some required fields cannot be promoted (People Picker fields), I need these for workflows etc.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "promoted"? And since you mention workflows, does this mean you need your archived data to still work with the workflows ? If my understanding is correct, your current situation would not allow this either way when you want your data exported as xml :/.

Comment: No on the archive there is no worklfows, as an item is archived when the last workflow finished. Promoted is the method that allows a field in the form to be visible in a document library column, and hence used in a workflow: https://formotus.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201042367-How-to-promote-fields-in-InfoPath-2010

Comment: Wouldn't my original suggestion still work? I'm not too fond of it, but creating a seperate form library "archive", adding an InfoPath form to it and copy the list item data in that form would work, since you do not need to have workflows running on them ?

Comment: How would I copy the data? only though custom code and it would boil down to generate the exact xml for the form. That is a lot of work. Since some fields are not promoted i cannot copy all those fields using a workflow or any OOB solutions

Comment: I'm not aware of any fields that could not be copied this way, and I don't know how many fields we are talking about here, but when you create a new InfoPath form, you could make something like this: Add a control to store each field's value, add a control that allows you to select the list item you want to "archive" (i.e. copy the values from) and using the built-in InfoPath rules, create an action that copies the value into the appropriate control when selecting the item from the dropdown.

Comment: I see what you mean, I want this to be automatic (via workflow) not a manual process, your solution is good even if manual was ok due to the amount of fields it would be a massive job to create all those rules and pull the data from a web service or something.